# How to reuse Connection with JavaMail to avoid AuthenticationFailedException: Too many login attempts?

Tags: java, scala, smtp, jakarta-mail

In my current implementation the `sendEmail` method is getting called many times in a loop to send emails to each individual email address. As a result about 95 emails are sent successfully but then the application fails with the following Error:

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Too many login attempts,
>   please try again later

How should I change the `sendEmail` method to fix this?

```
val EMAIL_FROM = "metricsEmail@gmail.com"

def sendEmail(text: String, recipient: String): Unit = {
    val properties = createProperties(HOST, PORT)
    val session: Session = Session.getInstance(properties)
    val message = createEmailMessage(EMAIL_FROM, properties, session, recipient, text)

    val transport: Transport = session.getTransport("smtp")
    transport.connect(EMAIL_FROM, PASSWORD)
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients)
  }
```

**UPD:** After refactoring the code as suggested in comments, I'm getting the following exception:

> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 421 4.7.0 Try again later,
>   closing connection. (MAIL)

```
  val properties: Properties = System.getProperties
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", HOST)
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", PORT)
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true")
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true")

  val session: Session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties)
  val transport: Transport = session.getTransport("smtp")
  transport.connect(DEFAULT_EMAIL_FROM, SENDER_PASSWORD)

    def sendEmail(text: String, recipient: String): Unit = {
        val message = createEmailMessage(EMAIL_FROM, properties, session, recipient, text)
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients)
      }
```

Comment: I would extract the **Session** and the **Transport**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Could you please give an example?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, `transport.connect(EMAIL_FROM, PASSWORD)` only needs to execute once, not every time you send an email. To that end, you should refactor to remove the creation of the properties, the obtaining of the session and transport, and the connection from transport away from the sendEmail method.

Comment: I've updated the question. After refactoring the code I'm getting `SMTPSendFailedException: 421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection. (MAIL)`

Comment: Did you google SMTP error 421? One possible cause is to have exceeded an account limit restriction. Since your earlier test exceeded the login attempts, perhaps you need an admin to reset the email account?

Comment: You're probably sending too many messages in too short of a time, so the server thinks you're sending spam.  You might need to artificially slow down your sending.

Comment: @BillShannon What would be a reasonable value in milliseconds for using in Thread.sleep()?

Comment: It depends entirely on your server.  You'll probably need to experiment to find out what works best.  You might want some sort of exponential backoff algorithm.